# How can one use Visual Studio for a single script instead for a whole project? C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I tried Visual Studio before, and really liked the looks and professionalism it has to it, and wanted to continue using it, but it turned out to be a big annoyance to study with, as I had to create a project and a program to test my scripts, so I left it.
!but! today I saw this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FuK3Erbqofc) and the guy in the video used Visual Studio like one would use codeblocks - how did he do it?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by 'scripts'? C++ is a compiled language, not a scripting language. I'm not familiar with codeblocks, can you describe how "one would use codeblocks" and perhaps people familiar with Visual Studio can help you achieve the same thing.

Comment: I guess OP wants to just write/open a cpp file and the make a runnable program with one click. This isn't how VS works.

Comment: Deviantfan - true, that's exactly what I want, I guess I will just not use visual studio until I'm going to make something bigger than a single script

Comment: They are not "scripts".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create an empty project (`New -> Project -> Visual C++ -> General -> Empty project`).

2) Right click your project in the `Solution Explorer` and add a new file (`Add -> New Item -> C++ File` and name it somehow (I always name it as `main.cpp`)

3) Double click the file and here you go!

Answer (score -1):

I found the way, sorry for the dumb question.
an answer in case somebody googles it - you need to open an empty project, and than in the project explorer menu right click and than click add, than add cpp file.

Comment: ...and it violates your own requirement of "no project creation"

Comment: @crashmstr It will compile the code. Do not confuse empty projects with empty solutions.